# How do I scroll in appium for my ios native app

Tags: uiscrollview, ui-automation, appium-ios

I am trying to scroll my native app using appium and iosdriver but its not working. Below are the two methods I have tried:

**Method 1:**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("direction", "down");
            params.put("element", (((RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"Go Green\"]"))).getId()));
            params.put("text", "Go Green");
            js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", params);
```

It gives NoSuchElementException where I have passed xpath of the element I want to scroll to. This element is not visible when the page loads so how do I scroll to it if appium can't find it.

**Method 2:**

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.press(PointOption.point(14,614)).moveTo(PointOption.point(136,503)).release().perform()
```

The absolute co-ordinates used in method 2 are x and y co-ordinates of the element i want to press and scroll to. I found them from appium inspector. It doesn't scroll down but goes back to previous page and starts typing in the text field there.

I am stuck on this since a week, any help is appreciated!

```
Java-client version : 7.0.0
Selenium : 3.141.59

Driver is :
AppiumDriver driver = new IOSDriver(service.getUrl(), cap);

Automation name in capabilities is : 
XCUITest
```

Comment: Have you change the coordinates to negative ? If I recall correctly , android and ios are different polar coordinates.

Comment: @john Sorry i mentioned Android driver by mistake I have corrected it, my test is for ios. I am using x and y co-ordinates from appium inspector. It works very well when i use only press function of TouchAction class. But moveTo does nothing as element is not visible on screen.

Comment: You will have to move till the element is visible etc by moving to other elements first.